# unable to reset the textinput and selectinput in r shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

Unable to reset the textinput and selectinput. I tried to create the action button reset. Also used observeEvent. could you please help. I want to understand why the reset with observeEvent is not working, also when I manually clear the textinput, the app gives error. Any reason

libraries:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(magrittr)
library(tidyverse)
```

UI part

```r
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Package with datasets and functions"),
    div(id='form',
    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            textInput('pkg','Package Name', value = NULL),
            actionButton("update", "Update View"),
            actionButton("reset", "Reset inputs"),
            helpText('Please enter the package name for which you want to see the list of datasets and functions (with parameters)'),
            br(),
            # br(),
            selectInput('dat','Datasets', choices = NULL, selected = NULL)
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
          tabsetPanel(
            id = 'dataset',
            tabPanel("List of Datasets in the Package", DTOutput("dataset1")),
            tabPanel("Datasets View", DTOutput("dataset2")),
            tabPanel("List of Functions with Parameters in the Package", verbatimTextOutput('func'))
        )
        )
    )
)
)
```

server part

```r
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  pkgs <- reactive({input$pkg})
  
  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    #pkgs() <- NULL
    updateSelectInput(session, 'dat','Datasets', choices = NULL, selected = NULL)
    updateTextInput('pkg','Package Name', value = NULL)
  })
  
  # 
  # if (!is.null(pkgs())){
  df <- reactive({
    # pksis <- require(input$pkg)
    # cat(pksis)
    # if (input$pkg %in% rownames(installed.packages()) == TRUE) {
  data_name1 <- data(package=input$pkg)
  data_name2 <- as_tibble(data_name1$results) %>% rename(name=Item, label=Title) %>% select(-LibPath, -Package)
  data_name2
    # } else {
    #   install.packages(input$pkg)
    #   library(input$pkg)
    #   data_name1 <- data(package=input$pkg)
    #   data_name2 <- as_tibble(data_name1$results) %>% rename(name=Item, label=Title) %>% select(-LibPath, -Package)
    #   data_name2
    # }
    })
  # }


  obse <- eventReactive(input$update, { df() })
  funct <- eventReactive(input$update, { paste0('package:',input$pkg) })
  
# if (!is.null(pkg1())){
  observe({
    req(obse())
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "dat", label = "Datasets", choices = c(df()$name), selected = df()$name[1])
    
  })
  

# }
  
  
  
  df2 <- reactive({
    req(obse())
    e <- new.env()
    library(package = input$pkg, character.only = TRUE)
    out <- data(list=input$dat, package = input$pkg, envir = e)
    e[[out]]
    # new <- input$dat
    # data(new, package = input$pkg)
    # cat(new)
  })
  
  
    output$dataset1 <- renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(obse())
    })
    
    output$dataset2 <- renderDataTable({
      df2()
    })
    
    output$func <- renderPrint({
      lsf.str(funct())
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$reset,{
      output$dataset1 <- renderDataTable({
        
      })
      
      output$dataset2 <- renderDataTable({
       
      })
      
      output$func <- renderPrint({
      
      })
      
    })
    
}
# Run the application 
# undebug(shinyApp)
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code makes the order of `update` and `reset` clearer in the server part.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(magrittr)
library(tidyverse)
require(DT)


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Package with datasets and functions"),
  div(id='form',
      # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          textInput('pkg','Package Name', value = NULL),
          actionButton("update", "Update View"),
          actionButton("reset", "Reset inputs"),
          helpText('Please enter the package name for which you want to see the list of datasets and functions (with parameters)'),
          br(),
          # br(),
          selectInput('dat','Datasets', choices = NULL, selected = NULL)
        ),
        
        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
          tabsetPanel(
            id = 'dataset',
            tabPanel("List of Datasets in the Package", DTOutput("dataset1")),
            tabPanel("Datasets View", DTOutput("dataset2")),
            tabPanel("List of Functions with Parameters in the Package", verbatimTextOutput('func'))
          )
        ) 
      ) 
      ) 
)
  
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    pkgs <- reactive({
      req(input$pkg)
      })
    
    ##### update
    observeEvent(input$update, {
      updateTextInput(inputId = 'pkg', value = pkgs())
      
      # check if this_package is installed
      if(system.file(package = pkgs()) == ""){
        updateSelectInput(session, 'dat', choices = NULL , selected = NULL)
      }
      else{
        # data sets in the package
        data_pkg <- data(package = pkgs())
        # names of data sets in the package
        data_names <- data_pkg$results[, "Item"]
        
        updateSelectInput(session, 'dat', choices = data_names, selected = data_names[1])
        
        
        ### dataset1 - data names
        output$dataset1 <- renderDataTable({
        DT::datatable(data.frame(data_names)) 

        })

        
        ### dataset3 - function list
        funs <- paste0('package:', pkgs()) 
        output$func <- renderPrint({
          lsf.str(funs)
        })
      }
    })
    
    
    ### dataset2 - selected dataset
    data_name <- reactive({
      req(input$dat)
    })
    
    output$dataset2 <- renderDataTable({
      e <- new.env()
      library(package = pkgs(), character.only = TRUE)
      out <- data(list=data_name(), package = pkgs(), envir = e)
      d2 <- e[[out]]
      
        #  some datasets are 3-d, e.g., "ozone" in package "plyr"
        if(length(dim(d2)) == 3){
          d2 <- d2[, , 1]
        }
        
        DT::datatable(d2)
    })      
    
    
    ##### reset
    observeEvent(input$reset, {

      updateTextInput(inputId = 'pkg',value = NULL)
      
      updateSelectInput(session, 'dat', choices = NULL , selected = NULL)
      
      output$dataset1 <- renderDataTable({
        DT::datatable(data.frame("No package selected" = NULL))
      })
      
    })

  }
  
  # Run the application 
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```